# Programmatically get list of controller action parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, action

I have a controller action

```
    public class MyController : SitecoreController
        {
            [AllowCrossSiteJson]
            public JsonResult AddSubscriptionsJson(string pipeDelimitedMailingListIds, 
                                                       string email)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

I know i can get the action Url using

```
Url.Action("AddSubscriptionsJson","MyController")
```

Is there a way to get the available parameters through code? In say an array / list of string?

Like this?

```
["pipeDelimitedMailingListIds","email"]
```

Comment: It usually helps to add a tag of the programming language/framework you're using ;)

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters . You need to write some helper method to do so but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the "best" way of achieving this but here is goes anyway. This sample code assumes the `GetParamNames()` method inside the same controller as the action method you are trying to pick for parameter names.

```
private List<string> GetParamNames(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method)
{
    var output = new List<string>();

    if (method != null && method.GetParameters().Length > 0)
    {
        foreach(var par in method.GetParameters())
            output.Add(par.Name) ;
    }

    return output;
}
```

and then from within the same controller you could call:

```
var parameters = GetParamNames(this.GetType().GetMethod("your action method name"));
```

the `GetParamNames()` method can obviously be placed in a more generic location like a shared utilities class for use by more than one class.

Hope this helps.

*Solution comes from a previous post [...names of method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters*)

Comment: Thank you, is there an mvc equivalent though? which takes the controller and action name to identify the method?

Comment: There may be a simple MVC method, but none that i know of unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the information Chris posted, the following link has the required information to fetch the MethodInfo for MVC actions - using the controller / action name to resolve the method: [How do I get the MethodInfo of an action, given action, controller and area names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042819/how-do-i-get-the-methodinfo-of-an-action-given-action-controller-and-area-name)